# Retrieving Serilogs after adding them from mongodb to my blazor view using ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, serilog-aspnetcore

I have a problem while sending the data from my controller using viewbag to my Blazor view, I want retrieve the logged data in my mongodb using Serilog.

I want help in using mongodb with .net to Get my logged data in the database and view it in my blazor view

```
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/fMfBOA7" data-context="false">
    <a href="//imgur.com/a/fMfBOA7"></a>
</blockquote>
<script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.